# Same menu for different taxonomies to reach different content

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, menus, taxonomy

I'm using a "location" taxonomy to show the same website for 4 different locations. Each of them will have the same categories which I want to display in a menu.

Is there anyway to create the same menu to show posts filtered by category but which also takes into account the current taxonomy the user is in? Can I do it directly using the wordpress panel or would I need to create a specific theme for it?

Basically, the site would have an index with 4 options, for example:

- London
- Cambridge
- Manchester
- Briton

Once the user click in any of them, a new menu will appear:

- Cars
- Tvs
- Trains
- Ships

So if I click in first in "Briton" and then in "Cars", the page should only show the posts with the category "cars" which are also inside the taxonomy "Briton".

Comment: Please do not ask the [same question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/176491/22534) twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating those categories Cars, Tvs, Trains and Ships as sub categories of locations?

Then you could have a navigation menu containing parent categories i.e Briton, Manchester etc.

Once a parent category is navigated to you could have a menu that uses the get_terms() function with the `parent` argument set to the current location term ID that lists all sub categories of the current location. Something like this.

```
$tax = get_query_var('taxonomy' );
$current_location_id = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), $tax ); 
$terms = get_terms( $tax, array(
    'parent' => $current_location_id
) );
```